# Multilevel (3 levels) nested models not able to update records, showing a 'Record was successfully updated' message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm still struggling to get Rails, please bear with me. I have a multi level nested Model relationship comprising: Quotation, which HAS_ONE RealServiceGroup, which HAS_MANY RealSegment(s), which in turn HAS_MANY RealQuoteLine(s) all tese are copied from their prototype models once the user determines which service group will be used (The prototype models are ommited for simplicity, just think that the Real is copied from a prototype model) So the copy goes as expected and the Real is created ok, but then to complete the Quotation, RealQuoteLine's 'quantity' and 'unit_price'  attributes need to be edited (updated) and persisted. My problem is that it won't persist the new values.
Here is the code involved:
app/models/quotation.rb

```rb
class Quotation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request
  has_one :service_group, class_name: "ServiceGroup"
  has_one :real_service_group, class_name: "RealServiceGroup", dependent: :destroy

  enum :state, %i[en_proceso enviada facturada comentada fondos], default: :en_proceso

  # after_create :get_real_service_group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_group, reject_if: ->(attributes){ attributes['title'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :real_service_group, reject_if: ->(attributes){ attributes['title'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  def get_real_service_group(service_group)
    real_service_group = RealServiceGroup.new(service_group.attributes.except('id'))
    real_service_group.title += ' (work) '
    real_service_group.quotation_id = self.id
    real_service_group.save
    service_group.segments.each do |segment|
      real_segment = real_service_group.real_segments.build(segment.attributes.except('id', 'service_group_id').merge(real_service_group_id: real_service_group.id))
      real_segment.title += ' (work) '
      real_segment.save
      segment.quote_lines.each do |quote_line|
        real_quote_line = real_segment.real_quote_lines.build(quote_line.attributes.except('id', 'segment_id').merge(real_segment_id: real_segment.id))
        real_quote_line.save
      end
    end
    real_service_group.save
    self.real_service_group = real_service_group
    save
  end
end
```

app/models/real_service_group.rb

```rb
class RealServiceGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quotation, inverse_of: :real_service_group, optional: true
  has_many :real_segments, class_name: 'RealSegment', dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :real_segments, reject_if: ->(attributes){ attributes['title'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/models/real_segment.rb

```rb
class RealSegment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :real_service_group
  has_many :real_quote_lines, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :real_quote_lines, reject_if: ->(attributes){ attributes['quote_concept'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/models/real_quote_line.rb

```rb
class RealQuoteLine < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :real_segment, class_name: "RealSegment"
end
```

app/controllers/quotation_controller.rb (just #create, #update and #quotation_params)

```rb
def create
    @quotation = Quotation.new(quotation_params)
    console
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quotation.save
        service_group = ServiceGroup.find(params[:quotation][:service_group_id])
        @quotation.get_real_service_group(service_group)
        format.html { redirect_to work_quotation_url(@quotation), notice: 'Se ha creado exitosamente la Cotización.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @quotation }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @quotation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        if @quotation.update(quotation_params)
          format.html { redirect_to quotation_url(@quotation), notice: "Quotation was successfully updated." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @quotation }
        else
          format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @quotation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
def quotation_params
      params.require(:quotation).permit(
        :request_id, :total, :state,
        real_service_group_attributes: {
          title: :title,
          tax_rate: :tax_rate,
          retencion: :retencion,
          usd_exchange_rate: :usd_exchange_rate,
          base_padron: :base_padron,
          impuesto_general_importacion: :impuesto_general_importacion,
          padron_importadores: :padron_importadores,
          real_segments_attributes: [
            :id,
            :title,
            :currency,
            :iva,
            :retention,
            real_quote_lines_attributes: [
              :id,
              :quote_concept,
              :quantity,
              :unit_price
            ]
          ]
        }
      )
    end
```

config/routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :quote_lines
  resources :service_groups
  resources :segments
  resources :real_quote_lines
  resources :quotations do
    collection do
      get 'line_fields'
    end
    member do
      get 'work'
    end
  end
  resources :requests
  resources :clients
  resources :notes
  resources :quotation_concepts

  get 'start_assign' => 'requests#unassigned'
  get 'request_inbox' => 'requests#inbox'
  
  get  'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get  'login'  => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login'  => 'sessions#create'
  
  resources :users
  root 'static_pages#main'
  
end
```

app/views/quotations/work.html.erb (this is not finished yet I need to add the Stimulus code to calculate subtotals and quotation -cotizacion- total)

```rb
<div>
  <h3>Ahora se completará la cotización</h3>
</div>
<table class="show-table" >
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Cotización:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.id %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Requerimiento:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.request.description %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fw-light">Cliente:</td>
    <td><%= @quotation.request.client.name %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<%= form_with(model: @quotation) do |form| %>
  <% @quotation.real_service_group.tap do |rsg| %>
    <% total_cotizacion = 0 %>
    <table class="cot-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Servicio:</th>
            <th colspan="3"><%= rsg.title %></th>
          </tr>
          <% rsg.real_segments.each do |rs| %>
            <tr>
              <th>Segmento:</th>
              <th><%= rs.title %></th>
              <th>Moneda:</th>
              <th><%= rs.currency %></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Concepto</th>
              <th>Cantidad</th>
              <th>Precio Unitario</th>
              <th>importe</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <% subtotal_segmento = 0 %>
            <% rs.real_quote_lines.each do |rql| %>
              <tr data-controller="linea-cotizacion">
                <td><%= rql.quote_concept %></td>
                <%= form.fields_for "real_service_group_attributes[real_segments_attributes][][real_quote_lines_attributes][]", rql do |quote_line_fields| %>
                    <% quote_line_fields.hidden_field :id %>
                    <td><%= quote_line_fields.number_field :quantity, data: { target: 'linea-cotizacion.quantity' } %></td>
                    <td>
                      <%= quote_line_fields.number_field :unit_price, 
                                                data: { 
                                                  target: 'linea-cotizacion.unitPrice',
                                                  action: 'focusout->linea-cotizacion#updateImporte'
                                                } %>
                    </td>
                    <%= content_tag(:td, '', id: 'importe', class: "fw-bold") %>
              </tr>
              <% end %> <%# fields_for %>
            <% end %> <%# rs.real_quote_lines %>
            <%# Aquí va el renglón para el subtotal del segmento %>
            <tr style="background-color: darkgray;">
              <td colspan="3" class="text-end">Subtotal</td>
              <td id="subtotal-segmento"><%= number_to_currency(subtotal_segmento) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %> <%# rs.real_segments %>
        <tr style="background-color: cadetblue;">
          <td colspan="3" class="text-end">Total</td>
          <td><%= number_to_currency(total_cotizacion) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <% end %> <%# rsg.real_service_group.tap %>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit "Guardar Cotización", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %> <%# form_with %>
```

And finally, this is what I get in the console (log):

```
19:37:45 web.1  | Started PATCH "/quotations/58" for ::1 at 2023-08-31 19:37:45 -0600
19:37:45 web.1  | Processing by QuotationsController#update as TURBO_STREAM
19:37:45 web.1  |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "quotation"=>{"real_service_group_attributes"=>{"real_segments_attributes"=>[{"real_quote_lines_attributes"=>{"117"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"134.0"}, "118"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"154.0"}, "119"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"15.0"}}}]}}, "commit"=>"Guardar Cotización", "id"=>"58"}
19:37:45 web.1  |   Quotation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "quotations".* FROM "quotations" WHERE "quotations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 58], ["LIMIT", 1]]
19:37:45 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:77:in `set_quotation'
19:37:45 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
19:37:45 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in update'
19:37:45 web.1  |   RealServiceGroup Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "real_service_groups".* FROM "real_service_groups" WHERE "real_service_groups"."quotation_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["quotation_id", 58], ["LIMIT", 1]]
19:37:45 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in update'
19:37:45 web.1  |   Request Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
19:37:45 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in update'
19:37:45 web.1  |   TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  COMMIT
19:37:45 web.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/quotations_controller.rb:52:in `block in update'
19:37:45 web.1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/quotations/58
19:37:45 web.1  | Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms | Allocations: 7940)
19:37:45 web.1  | 
19:37:45 web.1  | 
19:37:45 web.1  | Started GET "/quotations/58" for ::1 at 2023-08-31 19:37:45 -0600
19:37:45 web.1  | Processing by QuotationsController#show as TURBO_STREAM
19:37:45 web.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"58"}
```

This is a screenshot of what I get:
[image: App screenshot]

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: Take a look at the [`form_for` examples for nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for-label-Nested+Attributes+Examples) in the docs. You're doing things very wrong with `form.fields_for "real_service_group[real_segments_attributes][][real_quote_lines_attributes][]"`

Comment: @smathy, can you provide more insight please? I read the documentation you directed me, but cannot find where I'm doing wrong, I get confused by the several levels I am using, parameters seem to be ok: Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "quotation"=>{"real_service_group_attributes"=>{"real_segments_attributes"=>[{"real_quote_lines_attributes"=>{"75"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"134.0"}, "76"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"154.0"}, "77"=>{"quantity"=>"10", "unit_price"=>"15.0"}}}]}}, "commit"=>"Guardar Cotización", "id"=>"44"}

Answer (score 0):

In your view template, where there is `real_service_group[real_segments_attributes][][real_quote_lines_attributes][]`, try adding `_attributes`, like this:

```
<%= form.fields_for "real_service_group_attributes[real_segments_attributes][][real_quote_lines_attributes][]", rql do |quote_line_fields| %>
```

Comment: Rigth! This gets rid of the 'Unpermitted parameter' message, silly me, but it is still not persisting the edited quantity value